# Is there a way to filter users in AAD to list users without registered/joined devices?

Tags: powershell, module, azure-active-directory

I'm looking for way to filter out all users in my AAD tenant that don't have a registered/joined device.

Get-AzureADUser -All $true

Lists all the users, but what filter can I use or how can I retrieve other properties to show this?

I'm still new with AAD and PowerShell, so trying various approaches unsuccessfully...

Comment: Stack overflow is not a place to get your scripts written for you.  Users here will generally want to see what you've tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but probably something like:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | 
    Where-Object { @(Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId $_.ObjectId -All $true).Count -eq 0 }
```

Comment: Hey, it's exactly what I needed. I got lazy and figured Get-AADUser has the required device properties. Thank you, Theo ;)